# Firebase : How to query data with unknown key

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this JSON Database:

[image]

I am trying to upload a given Score to a certain Post. My problem is that I don't know how to get for example the key, **-KyCpxtBCXiHcEA49DNZ**, which is generated in a different Class by:

```
 self.randomkey = [[ref child:self.currentuser.uid] childByAutoId].key;
```

So far this is what I have:

```
 self.randomkey = [[ref child:self.currentuser.uid] childByAutoId].key;

 NSDictionary *updatescore = @{
                           @"Score": @"1", // For example
                       };

 NSDictionary *childUpdates = @{[@"/Posts/" stringByAppendingString:self.randomkey]: updatescore};
```

What makes every post unique is actually the key I am trying to get. I've come across the **queryEqualToValue** which I could use to query the data inside that key.

Things I've tried:

1. Query to get all posts, and filter the ones that match with the UserID. Problem is that 1 user can have many posts
2. Run the code I mentioned. Issue is that it generated a new random key. This will result in a new branch under "Posts".
3. Find some node which can related both Posts and Users nodes, but as I said, 1 user can have many posts.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?. I am using Objective-C.

Comment: How are you retrieving posts? Are you displaying them on a tableview?

Comment: Basically I have a NSMutableArray named "ScoreArray", which get the data from a Query [[rootRef child:@"Posts"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot). They show fine in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. And yeah, I am displaying them in a TableView. Thanks :)

Comment: I suggest you also save the key `-KyCpxtBCXiHcEA49DNZ` inside your posts and you should be able to query it like how you query all the other items in your post onto your tableview.

Comment: That's something I thought before. But how could that help? I mean the issue is not about displaying the scores in the tableview. The issue is about that I can have 1 or 100 keys to update a particular score.

Comment: If you can access a post on a tableview, then you'll be able to access the key. Once you access that key, you can go ahead and update or make changes to your firebase database. I think that should work, or maybe I don't understand your question fully.

Comment: You actually gave me an idea. What I can do is to save the key in another child node along with the other postdata in Firebase, and then query them and save them in a NSMutablearray in the same way that I save the other post data. In this way, I can always access the "arrayofkeys objectAt[tindexpath.row]". Thanks :)

Comment: I got to do what you told me, and it worked as expected :) . Only thing now is that after didselectrowatindexpath is called, the tableview seems to be refreshed automatically, that is, the cells appear as duplicated (if there are 2 cells, 4 will show up). Is that normal?